# Build URL upon submit using select values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a URL based upon the selection of several select boxes. I've found several examples where people have wanted to redirect users to a URL based on a select box selection without clicking a submit button, but I've not been able to create a script which takes all the values of several select boxes and then builds a URL and sends the user to that URL upon submit. Here is the code I have so far, but it isn't working:

```
<form method="post" id="searchform">
<select class="dropdown" id="country">
<option value="england">england</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown" id="sleeps">
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown" id="pets">
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" onclick="showURL();" />
</form>

function showURL(){
    var d1 = $("#country").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var d2 = $("#sleeps").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var d3 = $("#pets").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var url = ("http://www.blah.com/"+d1+"?sleeps="+d2+"&pets="+d3);

    window.location = url;
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RrS8L/

Can anybody suggest a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Jamie

Answer (score 3):

Just place your code in body after `DOM` is created.

[image]

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/324gu/)</kbd>

```
function showURL() {
    var d1 = $("#country").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var d2 = $("#sleeps").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var d3 = $("#pets").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var url = ("http://www.blah.com/" + d1 + "?sleeps=" + d2 + "&pets=" + d3);
    alert(url);
    window.location = url;
    return false;
}
```

---

Or place you code in `head`

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/324gu/1)</kbd>

[image]

---

if you want disable form submission commented by [Tom Chung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3041843/tom-chung)

```
<input onclick="showURL();return false;"
```

Comment: Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Comment: @TomChung That's because there is no such page in fiddle.

Comment: I don't think that is what @Jamie H wants.

Comment: @TomChung What does OP want ?

Comment: @TomChung added your suggestion to answer\ .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solutions

Both example works:

http://jsfiddle.net/RrS8L/9/

http://jsfiddle.net/RrS8L/10/

```
<input onclick="showURL();return false;" type="submit" name="button" id="button" />
```

Or

```
function showURL(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var d1 = $("#country").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var d2 = $("#sleeps").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var d3 = $("#pets").find(":selected").attr("value");
    var url = ("http://www.blah.com/" + d1 + "?sleeps=" + d2 + "&pets=" + d3);
    window.location = url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Art of Links with Javascript

*A handy little answer by howderek*

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/RrS8L/22/**

**Step 1: Creating links that pass data with JavaScript**

You already had a nice little function for generating a URL, but it needed a little modification in order to be more easily parsed. I made everything come after the `?` in order to better differentiate between the location and the data being passed to that page, as well as organizing the code a little nicer. Here is my modified `showURL`

```
function showURL() {
    var d1 = $("#country").find(":selected").attr("value"),
        d2 = $("#sleeps").find(":selected").attr("value"),
        d3 = $("#pets").find(":selected").attr("value"),
        url = encodeURI('http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/RrS8L/20/show/light/?country=' + d1 + "&sleeps=" + d2 + "&pets=" + d3);

    alert(url);
    document.location = url;
}
```

I got rid of your inline onclick, I made the form a div rather than a form (to prevent submission), and I made the `input type="submit"` into a `button`

I also created a paragraph to display results.

```
<p id="results">There was no information passed through the URL.</p>
<div id="dogform">
    <select class="dropdown" id="country">
        <option value="England">England</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="the United States of America">Murica</option>
        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
    </select>
    <select class="dropdown" id="sleeps">
        <option value="a few">Less than 4 hours</option>
        <option value="four to eight">4-8 hours</option>
        <option value="many">More than 8 hours</option>
    </select>
    <select class="dropdown" id="pets">
        <option value="nonexistent">None</option>
        <option value="beloved">One</option>
        <option value="many">Lots</option>
    </select>
    <button id="submit">Do stuff.</button>
</div>
```

**Step 2: Reading URLs with JavaScript**

I wrote a function a while back to read URL keys. It returns an object made of strings that are named after the keys. This allows you to read the values stored in the URL easily.

```
function urlAnalyze(url) {
    if (url == undefined) {
        var url = document.location.toString();
    }
    url = unescape(url);
    //seperates the parts of the url
    var parts = url.split("?");
    //splits into sperate key=values
    if (parts[1] == undefined) {
        return 1;
    }
    var keyValues = parts[1].split("&");
    var key = function () {}
    keyValues.forEach(function (keyValue) {
        var keyAndValue = keyValue.split("=");
        key[keyAndValue[0]] = keyAndValue[1];
    });
    return key;
}

$('#submit').click(showURL);

keys = urlAnalyze();

if (keys['country']) {
    $('#results').html('In ' + keys['country'] + ', people like to sleep for ' + keys['sleeps'] + ' hours after walking their ' + keys['pets'] + ' pets.');
}
```

I also made it easy to see what the URL inside of the JSFiddle is:

```
$('#results')[0].innerHTML += '<br><br>URL of this: ' + document.location;
```

You will have to replace the links to JSFiddle with the appropriate links to your website, but I believe that this should answer your question.

Here is an example of my usage of my function `URLTools` in one of my projects: http://howderek.com/projects/WordEngine/?q=this%20value%20was%20passed%20through%20the%20URL%20and%20read%20by%20javascript

Enjoy!